# how to update apt-key list in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM  mariadb:10.1.21

COPY mariadb.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d

RUN apt-get update                                      \
    && apt-get install --assume-yes mariadb-backup-10.1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

when I'm running `docker build .` the `apt-get update` command throws errors:

> Get:8 https://repo.percona.com jessie/main amd64 Packages [22.1 kB]
> Get:9 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
> W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1668892417 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA8E81B4331F7F50
> W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1668891673
> W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1668891673
> W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I know how to update the key-list following [this](https://linux-audit.com/how-to-solve-an-expired-key-keyexpired-with-apt/) tutorial on my local machine. But how do I update the keys for the Dockerfile? I ran `apt-key list` inside the docker container and got a bunch of expired keys. Or do I just update the mariadb image version at the top?